# Django - save copy of instance in inherited model

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Using Django 2.1.5, I have one model that is completely inherited by another model. Both tables in DB. I want to save 'revisions' of the model as the inherited model. All fields should be the same at the time of the copy (including the id/pk).

What's the right and quick way to copy the instance of the parent model to the inherited?

Let's say these are the models (but with a lot of fields, foreign keys, json fields..):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    identifier = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    revision = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class MyModelRevisions(MyModel):
    pass
```

Now, I want to take an instance of MyModel and completely copy it to MyModelRevisions.
I thought of something like this:

```
model_revision = MyModelRevisions(MyModel.objects.get(pk=my_model.pk))
model_revision.save()
```

But I'm getting an error message saying that the title of my_model is not a valid UUID.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be something like serialize/deserialize the object to create a new one:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

revision = MyModelRevisions(**model_to_dict(my_model_instance, fields=['id', 'identifier', 'title', 'revision']))
revision.save()
```

But maybe you want to give a look to something like django-reversion